# Problems while using python-vlc (libvlc)(win error 126)

Tags: python, error-handling, libvlc, python-vlc

so I am new to this module and a error shows up I looked various questions and I found that I should put libvlc.dll to another path but I don't know where to paste this dll file can anyone tell where to paste this dll file
this error shows up is there any other way to to resolve this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vlimp.py", line 1, in <module>
    import vlc
  File "C:\Users\SONY\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\vlc.py", line 210, in <module>
    dll, plugin_path  = find_lib()
  File "C:\Users\SONY\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\vlc.py", line 173, in find_lib
    dll = ctypes.CDLL(p)
  File "C:\Users\SONY\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 348, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
```

also I am using 64 bit python 3.6 and vlc both

Comment: put the dll next to your exe